# How to resize HTML content in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

Is there a way where I can resize the HTML content to be displayed in the UIWebview. Some of the HTML content displays properly, but some of the content do not fit properly into the UIWebView. I'm using viewport and it works for HTML content size that are width:320 height:656, but doesn't work for sizes that are width:648 height:2589. The view size is width:320 height:480. Any general help would be great thanks.

http://gyazo.com/673a2f8a1a6e1077ce873bc34a3a9068

This is the viewport I'm using:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width;  minimum-scale=0.3; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=no'>
```

Comment: have you tried ticking the option 'Scales page to fit' on the 'UIWebView' object in 'Storyboard' or  the 'UIWebView' @property?

Comment: Yes I have done that, but that still doesn't work. Thanks for the reply. I'm using Swift by the way.